# Error when using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I am trying to solve a system of differential equations as follows:

```
L1 = 5.0;
L2 = 0.43;
d = 0.0056;
g = 9.8;
h1 = 5.0;
h2 = 0.43;
A1 = 0.00001;
A2 = 0.001;
p0 = 100000;
v0 = 0.001;
NDSolve[{P[t] - 
1*1000*10*
 L2 == (1000/(2*0.0056)*y[t]^2*
  L2*(0.316*(1000*y[t]*0.0056/0.00089))^(-0.25)) + 
500*01.7*y[t]^2, (1000*10*L1 - 
 P[t]) == (1000/(2*0.0056)*z[t]^2*
  L1*(0.316*(1000*z[t]*0.0056/0.00089))^(-0.25)) + 
500*01.7*z[t]^2, (y[t] - z[t])*0.0001 == v'[t], 
P[t] == p0*v0/v[t],P[0]==100000,v[0]==0.001}, {P, v, y, z}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Uppon ruuning the comand I get the following error message:"NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.".
How can I make this work ?

Comment: Is this a system of differential equations or something else?

Comment: @zhk Looks like a DAE system with 1 differential equation and 3 algebraic ones.

Answer (score 2):

I plugged your initial conditions into your equations

```
{P[t] - 1*1000*10*L2 == (1000/(2*0.0056)*y[t]^2*
   L2*(0.316*(1000*y[t]*0.0056/0.00089))^(-0.25)) + 500*01.7*y[t]^2,
 (1000*10*L1 - P[t]) == (1000/(2*0.0056)*z[t]^2*
   L1*(0.316*(1000*z[t]*0.0056/0.00089))^(-0.25)) + 500*01.7*z[t]^2,
 (y[t] - z[t])*0.0001 == v'[t], P[t] == p0*v0/v[t]}
/. t -> 0 /. {P[0] -> 100000, v[0] -> 0.001}
```

and got the following output:

```
(* {95700. == 5749.49 y[0]^1.75 + 850. y[0]^2, 
 -50000. == 66854.5 z[0]^1.75 + 850. z[0]^2, 
 0.0001 (y[0] - z[0]) == v'[0], True} *)
```

Now let's see if we can find `y[0]` and `z[0]` that satisfy the first two algebraic equations:

```
Solve[95700.` == 5749.487805231354` y[0]^1.75` + 850.` y[0]^2, y[0]]
(* {{y[0] -> 4.46244}} -- good *) 

Solve[-50000.` == 66854.50936315529` z[0]^1.75` + 850.` z[0]^2, z[0]]
(* {{z[0] -> -0.184864 - 0.821224 I}, {z[0] -> -0.184864 + 0.821224 I}}
  -- two complex solutions = bad? *)
```

Without knowing anything about the physical nature of your equations, I tried flipping the sign of the left hand side of the second equation.  That resolved the initial conditions and `NDSolve` ran.  So I'd check to make sure the numbers are right and that the initial conditions can be met.

Answer (score 2):

There are 64 branches of the solution of the system of equations, not all of them are real, four of them are shown in this example

```
    L1 = 5.0;
L2 = 0.43;
d = 0.0056;
g = 9.8;
h1 = 5.0;
h2 = 0.43;
A1 = 0.00001;
A2 = 0.001;
p0 = 100000;
v0 = 0.001;
P[t_] := p0*v0/v[t]

y1[t_, i_] := 
 y[t] /. Solve[
    P[t] - 1*1000*10*
       L2 == (1000/(2*0.0056)*y[t]^2*
        L2*(0.316*(1000*y[t]*0.0056/0.00089))^(-0.25)) + 
      500*01.7*y[t]^2, y[t]][[i]]
z1[t_, i_] := 
 z[t] /. Solve[(1000*10*L1 - 
       P[t]) == (1000/(2*0.0056)*z[t]^2*
        L1*(0.316*(1000*z[t]*0.0056/0.00089))^(-0.25)) + 
      500*01.7*z[t]^2, z[t]][[i]]
sol11 = NDSolveValue[{(y1[t, 1] - z1[t, 1])*0.0001 == v'[t], 
    v[0] == 0.001}, v[t], {t, 0, 1}];
sol12 = NDSolveValue[{(y1[t, 1] - z1[t, 2])*0.0001 == v'[t], 
    v[0] == 0.001}, v[t], {t, 0, 1}];
sol13 = NDSolveValue[{(y1[t, 1] - z1[t, 3])*0.0001 == v'[t], 
    v[0] == 0.001}, v[t], {t, 0, 1}];
sol88 = NDSolveValue[{(y1[t, 8] - z1[t, 8])*0.0001 == v'[t], 
    v[0] == 0.001}, v[t], {t, 0, 1}];
{Plot[sol11, {t, 0, 1}], Plot[sol12, {t, 0, 1}], 
 Plot[Re[sol13], {t, 0, 1}], Plot[sol88, {t, 0, 1}]}
```

[image: fig1]